# my buttons are bugged

Tags: jquery, html

so I'm making a site for someone and I want to make buttons that show episode numbers, and that's how I got the idea to make buttons so they could switch between episodes, now I have this bug:

[the bug](https://gyazo.com/9016f57d74a67f1ba969e640a36d0ab8)

[image]

I tried finding a solution but couldn't, 
here's my jQuery

```js
$('#next1').click(function() {
  sixth = "<li class='liclass1' style='margin-left: 10px;'><a href=''> 6 </a></li>";
  seventh = "<li class='liclass1'><a href=''> 7 </a></li>";
  eighth = "<li class='liclass1'><a href=''> 8 </a></li>";
  nineth = "<li class='liclass1'><a href=''> 9 </a></li>";
  tenth = "<li class='liclass1'><a href=''> 10 </a></li>";
  arrownext = "<li id='next2' style='font-size: 70px;color: black;'> &#10142; </li>";
  arrowbefore = "<li id='before1' style='transform: rotate(180deg);display: inline-block;font-size: 70px;color: black;'> &#10142; </li>";
  $('.liclass').hide('fast');
  $('#next1').hide('fast')
  $('#qnaul').append(sixth);
  $('#qnaul').append(seventh);
  $('#qnaul').append(eighth);
  $('#qnaul').append(arrowbefore);
  $('#qnaul').append(nineth);
  $('#qnaul').append(tenth);
  $('#qnaul').append(arrownext);
  $('#before1').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  });
  $('#next2').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
  }, function() {
    $(this).css("color", "black");
  });
  $('#before1').click(function() {
    $('.liclass1').hide('fast');
    $('#before1').hide('fast');
    $('#next2').hide('fast');
    $('.liclass').show('fast');
    $('#next1').show('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 style="font-family: bebas;">Questions and Answers</h1>
  <ul id="qnaul">
    <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 0px;height: 100px;" class="liclass"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vlZ7Log_uoE">1</a>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;" class="liclass"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AFdJzSGab-8">2</a>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;" class="liclass"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0TBFCpTTkj0">3</a>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 90px;" class="liclass"><a href="">4</a>
    </li>
    <li style="width: 20%;margin-left: 30px;border: 0;" class="liclass"><a href="">5</a>
    </li>
    <li id="next1" style="font-size: 110px;">&#10142;</li>
  </ul>
  <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="400" allowfullscreen="yes" src="" frameborder="0" style="margin-left: 200px;margin-bottom: 10px;background-color: black;"></iframe>
</div>
```

whenever I click the return and next like 2 times i then can't press the return button again

Comment: what is the bug here

Comment: I click for a couple of times and then I can't go back anymore

Comment: Look at the end

Comment: Please mention bug in question, else people wont be able to understand question.

Comment: You want to look into delegated event binding

Comment: sorry im not very experienced with jQuery I just know the basics, can you show me a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pete I fixed it! used delegated event binding as you said.